# node.js install unmet dependencies on ubuntu saucy

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

While installing node.js on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js -y
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing -y
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm nodejs-dev -y
```

I am getting these

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: nodejs-dev
          Conflicts: npm
 nodejs-dev : Depends: nodejs (= 0.10.15~dfsg1-4) but 0.10.22-1chl1~saucy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I tackle this?

Comment: Face same problem on clean system. On fresh installation of 12.04LTS works well